# PHP: Create config fucntion to set or retrieve value globally

Tags: php, function, class

I am creating config property for class but to make it easily available I am creating a function with `$key` and `$value` parameter to set config option.

I managed to get work it partially, but with this code it is not loading all config key define in the system but it is only loading the key if we call after the key defined.

So how I can make such thing so it will load all set key in the system regardless where I am calling the function.

## calling function to set config key

```
// set very first key
ss_config('use_ob', true);
// debug
do_print(ss_config()); // this is just a debugging function with pre and print_r

//output ( so here I want to load all set keys regardless either I am calling before or after set in the system)
Array
(
    [use_ob] => 1
)
```

## Setting another key

```
// after above output I set this
ss_config('hello', 'world');
// debug
do_print(ss_config());

// output
Array
(
    [use_ob] => 1
    [hello] => world
)
```

## Config function

```
/**
 * Global config settings
 * @param  string $key   config key
 * @param   mixed $value config value for the key
 *
 * @return array
 */
function ss_config( $key = NULL, $value = NULL )
{
    //$ss_config = qam_ss();

    if ( isset( $key ) && isset( $value ) ) {
        qam_ss()->ss_config[ $key ] = $value;
    } elseif ( isset( $key ) && !isset( $value ) ) {
        qam_ss()->ss_config[ $key ];
    }

    return qam_ss()->ss_config;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I think I got you wrong. To adapt the original code to be used in any class, see the sample.

To create a basic global config class, you can create something similar to the following:

```
class Foo
{
    private $configData = array();

    public function getConfig($key = null)
    {
        if (is_null($key) {
            return $this->configData;
        }

        if (isset($this->configData[$key]) {
            return $this->configData[$key];
        }
    }

    public function setConfig($key, $value)
    {
        $this->configData[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

use it like so:

```
$fooClass->setConfig('foo', 'bar');
echo $fooClass->getConfig('foo'); // bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference. So do you mean it is good idea to create separate class for `Config` instead of just adding property to main class? Also I instead of instantiating class every time, I want to allow developers to use a function. So will that be fine if I set the instance in function and return `$config` will I get all keys globally?

Comment: @CodeLover see the edited answer; It is usually better to split up functionality in classes. If you want a global config storage, that is best kept as an additional class. If you need to store some values important for your class, keep it in there like the example above now shows.  
If you need a more refined example, take a look at my [Github project](https://github.com/Radiergummi/libconfig).

Comment: Okay that works fine, but what if I want all registered config items? Actually, what I am looking is if I call config without key and that is even I am calling before I define the key and value the item should be available. If you see in my code I set `hello, world` item which is available if I call it after set, but not in the first `do_print`

Comment: I made another edit to enable calling `get()` without parameters, that way it returns the whole array. Why would you want to create an empty array item? Do you mean to store default values permanently?

Comment: I need all available config items just to see what config keys are available. Or is there any other way to see?

Comment: Well, as you construct a class instance at some point, you should populate your configuration there. Otherwise, instead of creating `$configData` as an empty array, you could just write `$configData = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => true)`. Be advised, though, that filling the array in your Constructor is better coding style.

Comment: Okay cool.. I understood the things.. Thanks a lot for your help